# What is the CROSS APPLY OPENJSON query for the laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using this query.

In database structure column_name into Json format like this :

```json
[
    {
        "Date": "2022-11-14T10:45:05.424+01:00",
        "Name": "nilesh1",
        "Level": "1"
    },
    {
        "Date": "2022-11-14T10:54:15.776+01:00",
        "Name": "nilesh2",
        "Level": "2"
    }
]
```

I have to use below query with Laravel eloquent:

```sql
select [customername] as [customerName]
from [opf_details] 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (column_name,'$') where JSON_VALUE(value,'$.Name') LIKE '%nilesh1%'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`whereRaw()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#raw-methods) with the [`crossJoin()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#cross-join-clause)

```
$results = DB::table('opf_details')
    ->select('customername as customerName')
    ->whereRaw("JSON_VALUE(column_name, '$.Name') LIKE '%nilesh1%'")
    ->crossJoin(DB::raw("OPENJSON(column_name, '$')"))
    ->get();
```

1. [`crossJoin()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#cross-join-clause)
2. [`whereRaw()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#raw-methods)

---

**Edit**

```
$customerName = DB::table('opf_details')
    ->selectRaw('customername as customerName')
    ->crossJoin(DB::raw("OPENJSON (column_name,'$')"))
    ->whereRaw("JSON_VALUE(value,'$.Name') LIKE '%nilesh1%'")
    ->get();
```

Comment: CROSS APPLY  and cross join is same?

Comment: crossJoin returning invalid column name there. If i am using cross apply then it is working fine.

Comment: it is returning the same query response

Comment: can you post the response here

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Invalid column name 'column_name'.

Answer (score 0):

I have done like this:

```
myModel::whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(`column_name`, '\{"Name":"nilesh2"}\')')
```

Comment: How to use that syntex in our eloquent query. CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (column_name,'$')